# How to get the app version in EditTexPreference android

Tags: android, androidx, edittextpreference

I would like to get the App Version in EditTextPreference for my app.

App Name:

--App Name --

Version

1.0

for example:

[image]

it should reflect the version name in build.gradle(app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code to get the app version name:

```
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
String pkgName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
PackageInfo pkgInfo = null;
try {
   pkgInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(pkgName, 0);
} 
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
String versionName = pkgInfo.versionName;
```

The versionName variable stores the version name.

For fragments:

```
PackageInfo pkgInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getActivity().getPackageName(), 0);
version = pkgInfo.versionName;
```

Comment: it's inside of a fragment @Dinux

Comment: put on onCreateView?

Comment: yes, you have to put in onCreateView @Kelvin